# Making multiple frames in a single program

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-instances

I always wondered on how can I make a program with multiple JFrames. I mean I just want one class to handle all the GUIs and stuff but how can I effectively do this? A lot of tutorials say that we make JFrame by inheriting from JFrame. But what If I want many frames?

Ex:
Title of Application in one frame with some options
Menu is one frame
Main working application is one frame
Like in a game.

But I am not sure if I am pertaining to JPanel? I am completely puzzled with the 2. I just want one un-moving frame but basically the content of the frame is changing.
When I click START for example, it will change to the gaming style of frame.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: *"A lot of tutorials say that we make JFrame by inheriting from JFrame. But what If I want many frames?"* Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one.  I fear you have been finding the wrong tutorials.  I recommend the [Java Tutorial: Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for the first link. Really useful! About the extending from JFrame, I know that in some cases I should just make instances of JFrame, separate frames get separate instances; but I somehow think that there is a better way than doing so

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you are looking for a `JFrame` with a `CardLayout`.  Some background:

A **JFrame** is the physical window.  It comes with a title bar and three buttons: minimize, maximize, and close.  Think of this as a picture frame.

A **JPanel** is a "content holder" of sorts.  Typically, you put your other components (buttons, animations, whatever) on a JPanel, and then slap that JPanel into a JFrame.  Using our picture frame example, a JPanel would be the photo paper you put in the picture frame.  The other components would then be the actual contents of the picture itself, and what you have at the end is a nice picture...or in your case, an application.

Setting the JFrame to utilize a `CardLayout` essentially lets you have multiple JPanels inside the same JFrame at once, while still only showing one at a time.  So for your application, you would have (at least) two JPanels: one for the menu, and one for the game.  When the app starts, you show the MenuPanel.  When the user clicks "start", you switch to the GamePanel.  The MenuPanel will be put in the background and will be inaccessible until you call it to the foreground again.

If, on the other hand, you create multiple JFrames, you will have two or more physically separate windows that can be dealt with individually.  This can actually be kind of cool for game development.  Although it takes more time to build and link the GUI for the second window, you can then have that window affect game settings in realtime (rate of fire, bullet strength, player speed, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are after is the [Card Layout](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html):

> A CardLayout object is a layout manager for a container. It treats
>   each component in the container as a card. Only one card is visible at
>   a time, and the container acts as a stack of cards. The first
>   component added to a CardLayout object is the visible component when
>   the container is first displayed.

You can see how it is used [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

This layout manager allows you to manage situations where your frame needs to be shared across various functions. In your case for instance, you could have a functionality to handle the *settings* section of the game and another one to handle the *actual* game itself.

You could then use the manager to switch between these particular items.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Desktopane() and InternalFrame() for multiple frame.
Internalframe quite similar to Jframe but it need to setVisible(true) or show() everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Which ever IDE you are using, you can create multiple JFrames in the same package, and have separate codes for each of them.

If you want to link each frame, you will have to create instances from each JFrame. for example, if when the button is pressed, we need to invoke a new Frame (that we have already created)

```
NewJFrame1 frame1=new NewJFrame1();

frame1.setVisible(true);
```

then you can decide what to with your current JFrame.
eg : (Hide, Close)